# Single Responsibility / Separation of Concerns PHP

Tags: php, oop, separation-of-concerns

we spent some time arguing about this topic at work today and I think I need to hear some other oppinions.

Starting point of our discussion was designing some kind of order class - i.e.

```
class order {

    private $productList; 

    public function __construct() 

        //some kind of constructor
    }

    public function getProductList()
    {
       return $this->productList;
    }

}
```

So the order object holds an abstract product list (basically a collection of products) on which we can perform certain actions / mass operations (i.e. get total amount of all products, get total tax etc). So far we all agreed on this design. But when it came to actually build this order list, we - let's say - disagreed :)

I would have started like this:

```
class productList {
    /** @var array */
    private $productList;

    public function add(Product $product)
    {
        $this>-productList[] = $product;
    }
}
```

There was also another idea using a factory:

```
class ProductListFactory {
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(ProductRepository $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function createFromOrderNumber($orderNumber)
    {
        $products = $this->productRepository->getAllProdctsForOrder($orderNumber);

        return new ProductList($products);
    }
}

class ProductList {
    /** @var array */
    private $products;

    public function __construct(array $products)
    {
        $this->products = $products;
    }
}
```

I can see the "charm" of using a factory here and not allowing to add new products to the list from "outside". But somehow this does not feel right to me. Perhaps anyone can enlighten me on this point :) Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to answer this in any way that won't boil down to "opinion". One could go meta and also argue that building an entire object for a "dinky" class project is overkill as well, making the entire question moot.

Comment: Depends on if the project is going to be long term.  I'd pick factory if it was going to be long term because it would allow you to change things without having to change too much. Say you wanted to construct things a little different. Like Marc B said it is an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I think the factory approach might be superior, in your case, because you're working with a team.  If it was just you, as long as your code is reasonable, it would make sense to write it in the way that makes the most sense to you.  When working with a team, however, you're working with different minds who each have different ideas about how something should be done.  Trying to version, re-factor, and extend code that's been written in that situation, but which doesn't have a defined methodology, can lead to all kinds of hair pulling scenarios.  Of course, you could define a methodology for the approach you suggested, but the factory method is a proven one, that will force people to write code that adheres to certain expectations.  It's intrinsically ordered, and intrinsically extensible.  If I were you, I would defer to my teammates in this situation.

Comment: I think you're right. Maybe it's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

What could drive your choice is the way one design or another will allow you to test easily your code. 
The ProductListFactory could be injected with a productRepository mock so it's a good point for testing.

PS: I hope you didn't code you add function like this, or you will certainly be disappointed ;)

$this>-productList[] = $product;

Comment: It could be argued that the other method works easily for testing as well.  It all just depends on what you're feeding into the method.

Comment: :) This is no production code or even copy paste code - I just wanted to boil down the problem with some simple example. You're right about testing - but I would no test the factory - I would instantiate the ProductList with an array of mock products ...